# NOSQLDB categories..Need more info

Tags: graph, document, key-value, nosql

Are below the categories of NOSQL DB?

key value ,
columnar ,
document &
graph

I have idea on HBase, which is a columnar storage NOSQL DB; which stores data in key value pair. But what are document and graph type? Are these two also related to NOSQL DB?

Please share some link/details where from I can get more info in document and graph type NOSQL DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check out Martin Fowler introduction to NoSQL in youtube:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qI_g07C_Q5I

**ABSTRACT:**

*Martin gives a rapid introduction to NoSQL databases: where they came from, the nature of the data models they use, and the different way you have to think about consistency. From this he outlines what kinds of circumstances you should consider using them, why they will not make relational databases obsolete, and the important consequence of polyglot persistence.*

I'm sure it will clarify your vision about the different NoSQL databases.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Derick Rethans does a good talk introducing these concepts. The slides can be found at http://derickrethans.nl/talks/mongo-tut-tek15.pdf.

Derick explains this better than I but, to summarize:

**Key/Value**

Examples include Memcached and Redis. This type of NoSQL database simply stores a value under a key and retrieval is done using the key name.

**Column**

Examples include Cassandra, HBase, Riak and Amazon DynamoDB. This type of database stores all values for each entity in the same structure. For example, if a database had users with Twitter handles, the structure might be:

`{ twitter: [ { "derick" : "derickr" }, { "jeremy": "jmikola } ] }
{ emails: [ { "derick" : "derick@derickrethans.nl" } ] }`

**Graph**

Examples include Neo4j and OrientDB. This type of database is used for querying relations between entities - e.g. which users follow eachother on Twitter.

**Document**

Examples include CouchDB, MongoDB and Elasticsearch. This type of database stores formed JSON documents and usually provides the ability to query for documents containing particular key/value pairs.